# Why does using exactly the same build commands in Docker produce different hashes every time?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am building a simple CI process on CircleCI. It Dockerises a WordPress instance, determines if a remote registry has a copy of the resulting image, and if not, tags the image in a special format and pushes it.

However, I am finding in practice that images are *always* different, and I've traced the problem right to the top of the Dockerfile, where I am calling Alpine's `apk` command. The full command is:

```
RUN apk --update add git openssh-client
```

I've done two builds around 20 minutes apart, and this command is doing something different in each case. I am started on a fixed hash within Alpine 3.6.

Here is the first few lines of the penultimate build:

```
Step 1/42 : FROM alpine@sha256:3d44fa76c2c83ed9296e4508b436ff583397cac0f4bad85c2b4ecc193ddb5106 AS build
sha256:3d44fa76c2c83ed9296e4508b436ff583397cac0f4bad85c2b4ecc193ddb5106: Pulling from library/alpine

Digest: sha256:3d44fa76c2c83ed9296e4508b436ff583397cac0f4bad85c2b4ecc193ddb5106
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine@sha256:3d44fa76c2c83ed9296e4508b436ff583397cac0f4bad85c2b4ecc193ddb5106
 ---> 77144d8c6bdc
Step 2/42 : RUN apk --update add git openssh-client
 ---> Running in 4dee205378ad
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/8) Installing ca-certificates (20161130-r2)
(2/8) Installing libssh2 (1.8.0-r1)
(3/8) Installing libcurl (7.59.0-r0)
(4/8) Installing expat (2.2.0-r1)
(5/8) Installing pcre (8.41-r0)
(6/8) Installing git (2.13.5-r0)
(7/8) Installing openssh-keygen (7.5_p1-r2)
(8/8) Installing openssh-client (7.5_p1-r2)
Executing busybox-1.26.2-r9.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20161130-r2.trigger
OK: 28 MiB in 19 packages
 ---> 1c11addc5a9f
Removing intermediate container 4dee205378ad
Step 3/42 : WORKDIR /root
 ---> 0ec3661faedc
Removing intermediate container 3f0f8610abbc
```

And here is the latest build:

```
Step 1/42 : FROM alpine@sha256:3d44fa76c2c83ed9296e4508b436ff583397cac0f4bad85c2b4ecc193ddb5106 AS build
sha256:3d44fa76c2c83ed9296e4508b436ff583397cac0f4bad85c2b4ecc193ddb5106: Pulling from library/alpine

Digest: sha256:3d44fa76c2c83ed9296e4508b436ff583397cac0f4bad85c2b4ecc193ddb5106
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine@sha256:3d44fa76c2c83ed9296e4508b436ff583397cac0f4bad85c2b4ecc193ddb5106
 ---> 77144d8c6bdc
Step 2/42 : RUN apk --update add git openssh-client
 ---> Running in 8ad903516136
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/8) Installing ca-certificates (20161130-r2)
(2/8) Installing libssh2 (1.8.0-r1)
(3/8) Installing libcurl (7.59.0-r0)
(4/8) Installing expat (2.2.0-r1)
(5/8) Installing pcre (8.41-r0)
(6/8) Installing git (2.13.5-r0)
(7/8) Installing openssh-keygen (7.5_p1-r2)
(8/8) Installing openssh-client (7.5_p1-r2)
Executing busybox-1.26.2-r9.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20161130-r2.trigger
OK: 28 MiB in 19 packages
 ---> 4192a8ae6ba6
Removing intermediate container 8ad903516136
Step 3/42 : WORKDIR /root
 ---> 9f2a57c9923b
Removing intermediate container 050a150cf83f
```

For the convenience of readers, here's a graphical diff:

[image: Diff of Docker layer hashes]

My view is that this change in short order has happened too many times for there to be an actual OS update to an old version of Alpine (this is 3.6, the latest is 3.7). I think it might be writing the data or a timestamp in the update, which seems like a sensible thing for a package manager to do anyway.

However, I want two builds created within minutes to be hash identical, unless there are actual OS updates to be had. Would someone confirm what might be going on here under the covers, or explain what I can do to examine the actual change? For example, is there a sensible way in which Docker layers can be diffed?

If changes made by `apk` are never exactly reproducible, then is my best solution to create a fixed base image in my registry, install the software I need, and build atop that? I would have to set something to periodically rebuild it (e.g. every few weeks) so as to get security updates, but that's acceptable if it gets me stable build layers.

### Update

I have moved the `apk` calls to a separate build, and now I find that a `sed` command is changing the hash.

Here's the first run:

```
Step 15/39 : FROM registry.gitlab.com/username/jonblog-machine:latest
 ---> 5f854fc73292
Step 16/39 : RUN sed -i -r 's/memory_limit = \d+M/memory_limit = 30M/g' /etc/php7/php.ini
 ---> Running in d7205d0216f6
 ---> b64f045b6f51
```

And the second run:

```
Step 15/39 : FROM registry.gitlab.com/username/jonblog-machine:latest
 ---> 5f854fc73292
Step 16/39 : RUN sed -i -r 's/memory_limit = \d+M/memory_limit = 30M/g' /etc/php7/php.ini
 ---> Running in 152d628094ff
 ---> a397210c512b
```

This is perplexing: I start with `5f854fc73292` in both, but step 16 results in a new hash every time. (It starts at build 15 as this is a multi-stage build).

What can I do to see why I am getting different hashes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The layer hash includes the mtime timestamp on the file, which the `sed` command would change. You can see the spec for OCI images here which docker closely follows:

https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/master/layer.md#file-attributes

Comment: Ah, brilliant - that makes sense in terms of the Docker format, thanks. However, in terms of deploying an image, it's a disadvantage for me to regard this file as "changed" by virtue of a changed mtime (since it does the same thing). I'm looking to suppress the re-tagging of a new image if it is essentially unchanged, but resetting mtimes of all files I modify in the build seems to me to be rather inelegant. Would you say it is more "Dockerish" to always deploy (say in a CD system) even if it is not required?

Comment: The docker solution for me would be using the cache as designed that assumes the same command being run would have the same output. When you have the same command that should do something different, include a version number in the command, even as just an env var, to intentionally break the cache.

Comment: Of course! - thanks for the pointers. I am using CircleCI, and I thought I was using their cache mechanism to re-load Docker's cache for every build. I am wondering now if my config for that is broken, so I will look into that next.